# Overriding FormType In symfony

Tags: symfony, overriding

i have a problem how to overriding a FormType in my app in symfony2

my class is

```
class ContactType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('firstName', 'text', array('label' => 'mremi_contact.form.first_name'))
                ->add('lastName', 'text', array('label' => 'mremi_contact.form.last_name'))
                ->add('email', 'email', array('label' => 'mremi_contact.form.email'));

        if ($subjects = $this->subjectProvider->getSubjects()) {
            $builder
                    ->add('subject', 'choice', array(
                        'choices' => $subjects,
                        'label' => 'mremi_contact.form.subject',
            ));
        } else {
            $builder->add('subject', 'text', array('label' => 'mremi_contact.form.subject'));
        }

        $builder->add('message', 'textarea', array('label' => 'mremi_contact.form.message'));

        if ($this->captchaType) {
            $builder->add('captcha', $this->captchaType, array(
                'label' => 'mremi_contact.form.captcha',
                'mapped' => false,
            ));
        }

        $builder->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'mremi_contact.form_submit'));
    }

    public function getParent() {
        return 'mremi_contact';
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'mremi_contact_contact_custom';
    }

}
```

my services are : mybundle\ressources\config\services.yml

```
services:
    mremi_contact.custom_contact.form.type:
        class: Common\ContactBundle\Form\Type\ContactType
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: mremi_contact_contact_custom }
```

and i declared it in my app/config

```
# Mremi ContactBundle
mremi_contact:        
    form:
        type:              mremi_contact_contact_custom
        name:              contact_form
        validation_groups: [Default]
        subject_provider:  mremi_contact.subject_provider.noop
        captcha_type:      ewz_recaptcha

    email:
        mailer:            mremi_contact.mailer.twig_swift
        from:              []
        to:                
            - { address: thamer.nasri@gmail.com }
        template:          MremiContactBundle:Contact:email.txt.twig
```

the error is 
Could not load type "mremi_contact_contact_custom" 
plz help me thank you

Comment: Try using the service Id instead of the type name in your config

Comment: the same problem                                                                                                                                                                                                                             # Mremi ContactBundle
mremi_contact:
    store_data:            false
    contact_class:         Mremi\ContactBundle\Model\Contact
    contact:
        form:
            type: mremi_contact_customcontact

Comment: The Id is the bit directly under services, mremi_contact.custom_contact.form.type

Comment: mremi_contact:
    mremi_contact.form.contact_custom: mremi_contact_contact_custom i do it but no result :(

Comment: you should open an issue on the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/mremi/ContactBundle) ;-)